# How to get href from html refer to linktext?

Tags: python, html

I want get href refer to linktext.

i tried many way, but failed

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
......
<a href="www.link1.com">linktext1</a>
<a href="www.link2.com">linktext2</a>
......
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

def gethref(soup,word):
    magic!

print(gethref(soup, 'linktext1'))

#output : www.link1.com
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, with list comprehension,

```
linktext = "linktext1"
[a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True) if linktext in a.text.strip()]
```

You may safely replace `if condition` if you wish exact match.

```
[a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True) if linktext == a.text.strip()]
```

Comment: i want get herf just matching 'linktext'. not all

Comment: I am glad. Please upvote the answer if you find its useful.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using slightly simpler html here. You can identify the text in the link using `string` with `find`, then get that item's `parent` (which is the link element) and finally ask for the `href` attribute.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = '''\
... <a href='http://www.link1.com'>link text</a>
... '''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
>>> soup.find(string='link text').parent.attrs['href']
'http://www.link1.com'
```

Applied to your html it would be:

```
>>> soup.find(string='linktext1').parent.attrs['href']
'http://www.link1.com'
```